# Terms in the node startup message

Tags: erlang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the Erlang emulator info statements mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182025/what-do-the-erlang-emulator-info-statements-mean)

```
baskin@fun.hyd.baskin.com:/u/baskin> erl -name nodeA
Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
```

Hello,
What do these terms stand for?

```
[source] 
[smp:4:4] 
[rq:4] 
[async-threads:0] 
[hipe] 
[kernel-poll:false]
```

I know that smp [4:4] - means that smp vm is run with 4 schedulers (and 4 run queues?). Please help me understand the rest.
Are there ways to configure these? again, I know about disabling smp using smp --disable option, but not the rest.

Thanks
baskin

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182025/what-do-the-erlang-emulator-info-statements-mean