# Hybrid heap support in Erlang R15B02?

Tags: compilation, erlang, heap-memory, configure

Does Erlang R15B02 have support for hybrid heap?

I run `configure --enable-hybrid-heap blabla...` and `make` it, but no `[hybrid-heap]` flag showing:

```
$ erl
Erlang R15B02 (erts-5.9.2) [source] [64-bit halfword] [smp:16:16] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]
```

I get to know this flag from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185490/940313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experimental Hybrid heap implementation is gone in R15B02:

```
OTP-10105  Remove all code, documentation, options and diagnostic
       functions which were related to the experimental hybrid heap
       implementation.
```

See http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R15B02.readme

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't understand why is it gone? Do you have any idea?

Comment: It was experimental and the OTP team did not want to try to keep it alive going forward with the changes they are currently making to the system. I think the change paves the way for a better heap implementation further down the road though.

Comment: Official-ish reply: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-November/070576.html