# Regarding erlang tuning

Tags: erlang

I am new with erlang. I am trying to tune my erlang configuration for achieving higher connection rates on my mongooseim server. I found some people suggested to increase the async thread a little bit and enabling kernel poll. When I log into my erlang shell I see:

```
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]
```

now how can I increase async-threads to lets say 50 and turn on kernel-poll ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182025/what-do-the-erlang-emulator-info-statements-mean

Answer (score 2):

In addition to to the link added by Atomic_alarm in the comments below the question - ([What do the Erlang emulator info statements mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182025/what-do-the-erlang-emulator-info-statements-mean)). 
In Mongooseim you can set erl flags in `etc/vm.args`. To increase the number of async threads change the following line: `+A 5` to `+A 50`

Comment: it would be nice to quote the comment to make your answer easier to understand on it own.